# Error in controller. Unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My controller by nifty generators is having some block related problems.  I'm quite new to rails, so no doubt it's a simple problem.  Here is my error:

> /home/forrest/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': /home/forrest/code/luxeldb/app/models/maintenance_record.rb:16: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)

and here is my controller:

```
class MaintenanceRecordsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @maintenance_records = MaintenanceRecord.find(:all)
  end

  def show
    @maintenance_record = MaintenanceRecord.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @maintenance_record = MaintenanceRecord.new
  end

  def create
    @maintenance_record = MaintenanceRecord.new(params[:maintenance_record])
    if @maintenance_record.save
      redirect_to @maintenance_record, :notice => "Successfully created maintenance record."
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @maintenance_record = MaintenanceRecord.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @maintenance_record = MaintenanceRecord.find(params[:id])
    if @maintenance_record.update_attributes(params[:maintenance_record])
      redirect_to @maintenance_record, :notice  => "Successfully updated maintenance record."
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @maintenance_record = MaintenanceRecord.find(params[:id])
    @maintenance_record.destroy
    redirect_to maintenance_records_url, :notice => "Successfully destroyed maintenance record."
  end
end
```

Comment: The error is coming from your model, not the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading directly from the error message, the syntax error is in your `/home/forrest/code/luxeldb/app/models/maintenance_record.rb` file, not the controller.

You've missed an `end` keyword out, which Ruby spotted because it reached the end of the file (`$end`) when it was still waiting for an end keyword

Comment: Wow that was very obvious.  Thanks.  Im sleepy. Unfortunately I can't downvote my own question.

Comment: @light24bulbs S'OK, I did it for you.